# What do different \fontdimen<num> mean

Tags: fonts, tex-core, dimensions, font-metrics

I know that `\fontdimen<num>` returns some dimensions associated with the current font. What are they?

Comment: They are clearly explained in the TeXbook.

Comment: @MartinSchröder If the answer being in the TeX (or LaTeX) Book was grounds for not answering a question, this site would have a lot less traffic.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

---

For text fonts there are 7 parameters

**1 slant per pt** (used for italic correction)

**2 interword space** (standard width of the space )

**3 interword stretch** (amount the space  can stretch)

**4 interword shrink** (amount the space  can shrink)

**5 x-height** (the value for the `ex` unit)

**6 quad-width** (The `em` unit)

**7 extra space** (controls additional space after sentence punctuation)

---

Math symbol fonts (`\fam=2`)  must have at least 22 parameters, and extension fonts (used for large brackets etc) must have at least 13 parameters.

These font parameters are as followed (prefixed with `s` if they are used from `\fam2` and prefixed with `x` if used from extension fonts (normally `\fam3`)

The exact use of each parameter is described in appendix G of the TeXBook a brief (but hopefully correct) indication of the use of each parameter is given below.

**s5 x-height** (`ex` unit length)

**s6 quad**   (`em` unit length)

**s8  num1** (shift standard size numerator up by this amount)

**s9  num2** (alternative numerator shift)

**s10  num3** (alternative numerator shift)

**s11  denom1** (shift standard size denominator down by this amount)

**s12  denom2** (alternative  denominator shift)

**s13  sup1** (alternative superscript position)

**s14  sup2** (alternative superscript position)

**s15  sup3** (alternative superscript position)

**s16  sub1** (alternative subscript position)

**s17  sub2** (alternative subscript position)

**s18  sup-drop** (further control of superscript positioning)

**s19  sub-drop** (further control of subscript positioning)

**s20  delim1** (minimum display delimiter size)

**s21  delim2**  (minimum text delimiter size)

**s22  axis-height** (The height of the axis on which large operators and delimiters are centred)

**x8  default-rule-thickness** (default fraction line, also minimum separation between sub and super scripts)

**x9  big-op-spacing1** (controls limits spacing)

**x10  big-op-spacing2** (controls limits spacing)

**x11  big-op-spacing3** (controls limits spacing)

**x12  big-op-spacing4** (controls limits spacing)

**x13  big-op-spacing5** (controls limits spacing)

Comment: Is this heptaphoby?

Comment: @mafp :-) The first 7 text-oriented parameters are the same in text and math fonts but don't really play a part in math setting except for `s5` and `s6`

Comment: So what is the syntax to alter any one of these parameters, if they are alterable?

Comment: Ah, I see in the linked recent answer how you did it.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes you can set them like any normal register but you need to be a bit careful when as latex will set them and undo your settings  if the math setup changes or the font size changes or if the moon is in the 3rd quarter and it's a Friday or ...