# An easy way of obtaing such values as `ex` in font without `x`?

Tags: fonts

From an output on the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\font\meta logo10 at30pt

\meta
M{\hskip1em}E{\hskip1ex}T

\end{document}
```

I can guess that the value of `ex` in font `logo10` is equal to 0pt. Does it exist an easy, more natural way of obtaing such values? I know that I can read the METAFONT source of font, but it should be another way...

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8260/what-are-the-various-units-ex-em-in-pt-bp-dd-pc-expressed-in-mm/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

ex and em are fontdimen 5 and 6, see

[What do different \fontdimen<num> mean](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88991/what-does-different-fontdimennum-mean/88993#88993)

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\font\meta logo10 at30pt

\showthe\fontdimen5\meta
\showthe\fontdimen6\meta

\meta
M{\hskip1em}E{\hskip1ex}T

\end{document}
```

Produces

```
> 0.0pt.
<recently read> \meta 

l.7 \showthe\fontdimen5\meta

? 
> 23.99991pt.
<recently read> \meta 

l.8 \showthe\fontdimen6\meta
```

Comment: Oh, `\showthe`! I have tried `\the` without a success.

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke `\the` would work the same way, making text in the document rather than on the terminal. Perhaps you forgot the trailing `\meta` `\fontdimen` takes two arguments a number and a font.

Comment: I forgot to change back onto a normal font, hence my rather naive question.

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke :-) :-) good catch:-)

Comment: of course one might ask, why use `ex` for a horizontal space? (yes, i know it was in the original example.)