# ! Missing $ inserted.<inserted text>$ \textbf{Basic} & \textbf{x_1}

Tags: tables

I am new to TEX world . I am now working on thesis in TEX . I have the following code to show a table .

```
                              \begin{center}
                              \begin{tabular}{ | l | c |  r | l | c | r|  l | c |  }
                                \hline
                                    \textbf{Basic} & \textbf{x_1} & \textbf{x_2} & \textbf{x_3} & \textbf{s_1}  & \textbf{s_2}  & \textbf{s_3} &    \textbf{b} \\ \hline
                                    s1 &    2 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 10 \\ \hline
                                    s2 & 1 & 2  & -2 &  0 & 1 & 0 & 20 \\ \hline
                                    s3 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 5 \\ \hline
                                    Z & -2 & 1 & -2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ \hline
                                \hline
                              \end{tabular}
                            \end{center}
```

But TexMaker IDE shows the following error .

```
! Missing $ inserted.<inserted text>$ \textbf{Basic} & \textbf{x_1}
```

A snapshot of my error is provided below :
[image]

Here is my code :

[image]

Where is the error ?

Comment: subscripts need math mode so `\textbf{$x_1$}` but then you need math bold fonts.

Comment: `_` is a math-char. I would suggest you to do: $\mathbf{x_1}$ for the `x`s. It however, requires `amsmath`. Also all numbers should be typeset in `$$` to get mathematical fonts, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/185193/what-is-the-necessity-of-around-numbers

Comment: You also can use `\textsubscript` from the `subscript` package (in the LaTeX bundle `fragments`).

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I didn't say it wasn't ;) I also always have it! But if the OP didn't want to use it, for whatever reason... :)
I can now see that _however_ was a bad wording, English is not my primary language. I'll note that wording.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subscript needs the math mode. To change all your

```
x_index
```

to

```
$x_index$
```

will help you.