# Typesetting temperature, should I write the number inside dollars?

Tags: typography

Are there any advice which one is more preferable:

```
The temperature is $5$ degrees Celsius.
```

or

```
The temperature is 5 degrees Celsius.
```

Here, I don't want to use siunitx or anything similar to typeset the degree symbol.

Comment: If it's just informative, or part of the text, without dollars. If it's part of a problem, or with some calculation involved, then math. That's my point of view.

Comment: Duplicate http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/185193/3929

Comment: IMHO, documents should use the same font for math numbers as for textual numbers, so you shouldn't see any difference in the output. Packages like `{times}` violate this, so `$5$` would be in Computer Modern, and `5` would be in Times -- ugh! So, I think it's just up to your personal choice here.

Comment: @JohnWickerson What if you want to use old style figures?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should write numbers that are "equations" (not "text") as equations, i.e., in `\(...\)` (`$...$` is a semi-deprecated way of writing inline equations; I don't use it because it is too easy to mess up opening-closing with it). This because the text font might render digits *very* differently than the math font does. Most font combinations don't, so visually the effect is probably hard to notice most of the time.

Then the question becomes when a number is text and when it is math. If you reference, say, "chapter 15" it is clearly text, in your case (a temperature, or in general a value of some kind) I'd argue it it math.

Comment: It leaves me wondering why `$...$` is “semi-deprecated”. We all know that `$$...$$` is a Plain TeX definition that should not be used. The only benefit of `\(...\)` I see is compatibility with _some_ WordPress MathJax scripts that automatically detect inline and displayed formulæ using the slash-paren or slash-bracket pattern. However, there are some that correctly interpret dollar signs if they are not escaped. Besides that, source code like `let \(a\) equal to \(5\)` seems more messy to me than a clearer `let $a$ equal to $5$`. Again, who declared that it is semi-deprecated?