# Mathematical environment for a list of mathematical numerals (and mathematical numerals outside of equations)

Tags: math-mode, spacing

I've seen the three questions related to using $ around numbers/mathematical numerals in text outside of equations: [When to use math mode?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37168/when-to-use-math-mode);
[Numbers outside Math environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38820/numbers-outside-math-environment); and [What is the Necessity of $...$ Around Numbers?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/185193/what-is-the-necessity-of-around-numbers)

I have the following expression in a paragraph and I wish to avoid different glyphs for the numbers if I change the font:

```
contour levels at ($-2$, 2, 4, 8, 16 and~32)~$\times$~0.348$\sigma$
```

Would any of these below be recommended to achieve this (and ensure if it breaks across two lines that breaking occurs before the `and`)?

```
($-2$, $2$, $4$, $8$, $16$ and~$32$)~$\times$~$0.384\sigma$

($-2$, $2$, $4$, $8$, $16$ and~$32$)~$\times~0.384\sigma$

$(-2, 2, 4, 8, 16$ and~$32) \times 0.384\sigma$
```

or possibly using `\text{}` as suggested by marmot:

```
$(-2, 2, 4, 8, 16\text{ and }32) \times 0.384$
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Most likely someone will give you an answer that you'll like, but perhaps you might consider adding `$(-2, 2, 4, 8, 16\text{ and }32) \times 0.384$` to your list. In this example this is not too obvious, but if you consider e.g. `$\left(-2, \frac{2+\frac{1}{7}}{3}, 4, 8, 16\text{ and }32\right) \times 0.384$` then you see that at least in some situations this is "better" since it allows you to let LaTeX adjust the brackets.

Comment: It would help if you indicated what `(-2, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32)` denotes. Is it a row vector (an n-tuple), a collection of 6 scalar numbers, or something else still? The presence of the word "and" between "16" and "32" makes your example somewhat ambiguous in this regard.

Comment: @marmot -- there's a possibly great disadvantage to the code you suggest.  unless it nicely falls completely in the middle of a line, it will break only after the `\times`.  a string in `\text` won't break either -- it follows the math rules.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I fully agree with what you're saying. Note, however, that I was not suggesting to necessarily use this code, I was proposing to add this to the list such that someone like you could discuss all the pros and cons of the different possibilities.

Comment: @Mico this expression would be the equivalent of "contour levels at $-0.768$, 0.768, 1.536, 3.072, 6.144 and 12.288." (each value a multiple of sigma)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `xparse` and `expl3` you can get an easier syntax for input.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\numlist}{mo}
 {
  \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l_jacinta_numlist_in_seq { #1 }
  \seq_set_map:NNn \l_jacinta_numlist_out_seq \l_jacinta_numlist_in_seq { $##1$ }
  \IfValueT{#2}{ $($ }
  \seq_use:Nnnn \l_jacinta_numlist_out_seq
   { ~ and \nobreakspace } % two items
   { ,~ }                  % between items
   { ~ and \nobreakspace } % last two
  \IfValueT{#2}{ $)#2$ }
 }
\seq_new:N \l_jacinta_numlist_in_seq
\seq_new:N \l_jacinta_numlist_out_seq
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

Contour levels at \numlist{-2, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32}[\times0.348\sigma].

Contour levels at \numlist{-2, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32}.

Contour levels at \numlist{-2, 2}[\times0.348\sigma].

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: In case the numbers to be printed are not integers, one can use `\num{##1}` instead of `$##1$` (requires `\usepackage{siunitx}`).

Answer (score 1):

(Thanks for providing a comment with some additional information about the intended use and meaning of your code fragment.)

Since you're talking about five different contour levels, they're (logically speaking) not part of one and the same "formula". I'd therefore say that

```
($-2$, $2$, $4$, $8$, $16$ and~$32$)\hspace{0pt}${}\times0.384\sigma$
```

[image]

is the most appropriate form. (Feel free to add an "Oxford comma".) This makes TeX insert ordinary interword whitespace between the numbers in the parenthetic construct, it allows a line break after the closing parenthesis, and it provides for the right amount of spacing around the `\times` symbol if no linebreak occurs.