# How to change extra font parameters \xi8 - \xi13 ？

Tags: fonts

We can use `\fontdimenX` to modify the font parameters, where X can be 1 to 22. But how to modify the extra font parameters such as default rule thickness? Which is listed in Appendix G in TeXBook, Page 447.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The list is also

[What do different \fontdimen<num> mean](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88991/what-do-different-fontdimennum-mean/88993#88993)

The syntax is the same for all of them, just need to use the suitable font (`\textfont2` or `\textfont3`). I give a plain TeX example below, in latex it is the same but the timing needs to be synchronsied with the latex font setup (for example every size change changes the font assigned to `\textfont3`)

so rule thickness would be

[image]

```
\fontdimen8 \textfont3  =5cm

$ a \over b$

\bye
```

As Barbara comments below, this fontdimen  affects the space above and below the rule as well as the rule itself, which is mostly unfortunate and usually constrains the amount of variation it makes sense to have here.

Comment: you *would* have to choose the one that has the worst side effects.  (of course, this is what is requested.)  maybe you could provide a brief explanation of why this one is an example of unfortunate design. (one of the few really terrible flaws in the design.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton are you saying the AMS would not publish my document in this form? Shame.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. In my mind \fontdimen8 refers to s8(num1), and I want to access x8(default-rule-thickness). Are these two parameter joint or they have some relation?

Comment: BTW, my real goal is to shorten the minimal space limitation between superscript and subscript. Reading appendix G of the TeXBook, I think modify x8 is the only way to do this. (I've verified that the space in my document is limited by >=4{x8}, not any other parameters.) I'd appreciate it if there's other ways to achieve my goal without side effects.

Comment: @Ben fontdimen isn't a global value it is a _per font_  parameter `\fontdimen8` isn't usable as a length it parses for a font first. so `\fontdimen8 \textfont2` is s8 `\fontdimen8 \textfont3` is x8

Comment: @DavidCarlisle `\textfont2` and `\textfont3` should refer to different fonts, aren't they?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Do you mean that font family 3 has only x* parameters while font family 2 has only s* parameters?

Comment: @Ben a font can have any number of parameters (maximum value a power of 2, I forget how many exactly) but TeX requires that the fonts  specified for textfont 2 and 3 have at least 22 parameters each. the xi_8/sigma_8 (or s8/x8) notation is just shorthand for saying "fontdimen 8 of textfont 2" or "fontdimen 8 of textfont 3" every time. there are not different types of s and x parameters in any sense in the code.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks, now I'm clear with it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40712/discussion-between-ben-and-david-carlisle).