# em, ex, en? Which length units are font size dependent?

Tags: lengths

Length can be specified as `3em`, or `3.5ex`. What is required to 
make `4en` also valid? Are there any other font related length units?

Comment: What's the use? 1en=0.5em.

Comment: and if I wanted  `\aye` for the width of an `i`?

Comment: Why not `\fjord for the width of the ligature `fj``;o)?

Comment: `em` is _not_ the width of a character `m`!!!  so your comment about the width of an `i` seems misplaced, you can use `\fontcharwd` to find the width of a character in a font.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is no `en` unit. TFM fonts have font dimensions 5 and 6 which may be accessed as `ex` and `em` no other fontdimen corresponds directly to a unit.

see

[What do different \fontdimen<num> mean](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88991/what-do-different-fontdimennum-mean/88993#88993)

Note in comments you ask about the width of an `i` you can use e-tex `\fontcharwd` to find the width of a character or classically `\setbox0\hbox{i}... \wd0`  But this `em` and `ex` are not related to the width or height of the m and x characters they are just arbitrary lengths assigned by the font designer.

Comment: But there is an `\enspace` macro, which has sometimes lured me into thinking `en` is defined as a unit in LaTeX.

Comment: there's a `\bigskipamount` as well but that isn't a unit either,

Comment: True enough, but `en` is (or was, historically) a common printing term - often called a "nut" to distinguish it clearly from a "mutton" (em) when speaking.

Comment: @alephzero I know:-) but...