# Lengthen the fraction rule in MTPRO2

Tags: fractions

I'm now using MTPRO2 now. The fraction bar(rule) is too short for my taste(see the picture), thus I want to lengthen it everywhere in my document. How can I do it? Or it doesn't matter whether using MTPRO2 or not?

[image: demo]

Comment: You can't.  Only the thickness is adjustable via [`\fontdimen`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/88993/10995) parameters.

Comment: I see no difference with respect to the standard Computer Modern fonts, besides the glyphs in Times being a bit narrower.

Comment: I guess I'm out of date but what is MTPRO2? I tried `texdoc MTPRO2` but nothing was found.

Comment: @PeterWilson MathTimePro2. But it doesn't matter I think. Just think as in original LaTeX.

Comment: @egreg. Do you know how to change back to the Computer Modern style of that bar (circle corner style)? I only want to use part of the MTPro2 function though..

Comment: What do you mean by “circle corner style”? The ends of a fraction line are sharp as always in TeX.

Comment: @PeterWilson `mtpro2` can be freely downloaded from the PCTeX site, together with part of the fonts so to fulfill the needs when `\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2}` is called. The full version is commercial.

Answer (score 1):

## Longer fraction bar

`\frac` can be redefined to add additional space for the numerator and denominator to get a longer fraction line, for example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\let\OrgFrac\frac
\renewcommand*{\frac}[3][\,]{%
  \OrgFrac{#1\relax#2#1}{#1\relax#3#1}%
}

\begin{document}
\[
  \frac[]{1}{2},
  \frac{1}{2},
  \frac[\mkern4mu]{1}{2}
\]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

## Rounded line ends of fraction bar

If `circle corner style` means round line ends of the bar, then the following example overprints the bar by a line with rounded line ends via TikZ:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\makeatletter
\let\OrgFrac\frac
\newcommand*{\roundfrac}[2]{%
  \mathpalette{\@roundfrac{#1}{#2}}{}%
}
\newcommand*{\@roundfrac}[4]{%
  % #1: numerator
  % #2: denominator
  % #3: math style
  % #4: unused/empty
  \begingroup
    %\sbox0{$#3#1\m@th$}%
    %\sbox2{$\cramped[#3]{#2}\m@th$}%
    \edef\BarLineWidth{%
      \the\fontdimen8%
      \ifx\displaystyle#3\textfont
      \else\ifx\textstyle#3\textfont
      \else\ifx\scriptstyle#3\scriptfont
      \else\scriptscriptfont
      \fi\fi\fi
      3 %
    }%
    \sbox0{%
      \kern-\nulldelimiterspace
      $#3\OrgFrac{#1}{#2}\m@th$%
      \kern-\nulldelimiterspace
    }%
    \sbox2{$#3\vcenter{}$}% math axis
    \kern\nulldelimiterspace
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
      inner sep=0pt,
      outer sep=0pt,
      baseline=(frac.base),
      line cap=round,
      line width=\BarLineWidth,
    ]
      \node[anchor=base] (frac) {\copy0};
      \draw (frac.west |- 0, \ht2) -- (frac.east |- 0, \ht2);
    \end{tikzpicture}%
    \kern\nulldelimiterspace
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother
\let\frac\roundfrac

\begin{document}
\[
  \OrgFrac{1}{2};
  \frac{1}{2},
  \textstyle\frac{1}{2},
  \scriptstyle\frac{1}{2},
  \scriptscriptstyle\frac{1}{2}
\]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result with rounded line ends]

Of course, both the longer fraction bar and the rounded line ends can be combined. It is left as an easy exercise for the reader.