# Medium sized fraction macro, instead of using the nccmath package

Tags: math-mode, macros, scaling, fractions, nccmath

We could get good looking medium sized fractions using the **nccmath** package.  However, there may be some incompatibilities with other packages and I would prefer to get rid of that package, since I just want to use its medium fraction.  I created a macro to try to repoduce the smaller fraction (*not \tfrac* !), but I'm currently unable to get it right.  Here's a MWE showing the medium fraction and it's current reproduction with a macro:

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{nccmath,amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\newcommand*{\medfrac}[2]{\vcenter{\hbox{\scalebox{1}{\ensuremath{\frac{#1}{#2}}}}}}

\begin{document}

Blabla bla bla blabla :
    \begin{equation}
        \frac{1}{2} = \mfrac{1}{2} \: A = \medfrac{1}{2} \: A = \frac{1}{2} \: A.
    \end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Preview:

[image]

As you can see here, the **\medfrac** macro gives a tiny fraction, while using 1 as a scale parameter in the macro.  So what is going on, and how could we get the same output as **\mfrac**?

Comment: you are setting a textstyle fraction not displaystyle, but avoid applying `\scalebox` to text, nccmath does not use scaling at all,.

Comment: Which incompatibilities do you have? The only one I've observed is with the `\shortintertext` command from `mathtools`, and it is solved loading `nccmath` *before* `mathtools.

Comment: @Bernard, I don’t have incompatibilities yet, but my preamble is already a huge castle of cards, so I would prefer to get rid of packages I don’t absolutely need. So how should I define that medium fraction ?

Comment: @David, in what way is my macro a textsyle definition?  I don’t get it.

Comment: @Cham if you ignore the superfluous scalebox and ensuremath then you have `\hbox{$\frac{#1}{#2}$}` so a textstyle fraction.

Comment: I’m sorry, I’m not sure I understand. Maybe you could add an answer with the proper macro which creates the same medium fraction as the one from the package?

Comment: @Cham: in a displayed equation, you may try `\text{\smaller$ \frac ab $}`, but you'll have ti load `relsize`, and the fraction rules won't be exactly aligned with the other fraction rules. This being said, `nccmath` loads `amsmath` so you don't have to load the latter.

Comment: @Cham no, sorry if you want something that acts like that, just use the package or copy the definition of just that command from the package. I'm just explaining what is wrong with the code posted here.

Comment: Curently, I’m not in front of my computer so can’t test any LaTeX.

Comment: Another unrelated question (or maybe it’s related) :  why adding « * » alter the command \newcommand?

Answer (score 2):

It isn't clear why you don't want to use the package, but if not don't use `\scalebox` on text. This is a simple version, which only works for `\normalsize` text and displays a `\small` `\displaystyle` fraction with  tighter spacing around the fraction bar and raised slightly to align with the math axis of the outer equation, The font dimen parameters are listed in this answer

[What do different \fontdimen<num> mean](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88991/what-do-different-fontdimennum-mean/88993#88993)

[image]

The macro makes the third 1/2 here, with the nccmath mfrac for comparison shown in the final case.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,nccmath}
\newcommand\zfrac[2]{\text{\footnotesize\raisebox{.15ex}{%
\dimen0=\fontdimen8\textfont2  % numerator shift
\dimen2=\fontdimen11\textfont2 % denominator shift
\dimen4=\fontdimen8\textfont3  % fraction rule
$%
\fontdimen8\textfont2=.5\dimen0
\fontdimen11\textfont2=.5\dimen2
\fontdimen8\textfont3=1.1\dimen4
\dfrac{#1}{#2}$%
\fontdimen8\textfont2=\dimen0
\fontdimen11\textfont2=\dimen2
\fontdimen8\textfont3=\dimen4
}}}

\begin{document}

\[
\frac{1}{2}+\tfrac{1}{2}+\zfrac{1}{2}+\mfrac{1}{2}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: actually I think I over-compensated the fraction bar width 1.1 multiplier is probably too much.

Comment: Hmm, that's pretty complicated.  I'm a bit confused now, about using a macro without the **nccmath** package, or else simply using the package for the mfrac command only.

Comment: @Cham it's only a dozen lines of code, that's not really very complicated, it's just changing the font size, adjusting three parameters, setting a fraction then restoring them. But using a package is simpler, that's rather the point of packages.

Comment: I'm wondering why such a medium fraction isn't standard, by default, like **\tfrac**, **\dfrac**.

Comment: @Cham most documents have no need for such a construct (I've been using tex for 30 years and never used it for example)

Comment: The output is much nicer with \mfrac, in a series, for example.