# Enforcing uniform vertical spacing for sub and superscripts using different letters

Tags: math-mode, spacing, vertical-alignment

The following looks quite terrible, because `\ell`, `f` and `x` all have different sizes:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\begin{document}
$q_\ell^{\scriptscriptstyle {\alpha}_{c\ell}}
 q_f^{\scriptscriptstyle {\alpha}_{cf}}
 q_x^{\scriptscriptstyle {\alpha}_{cx}}
$\\[12pt]
$ c_f^{\scriptscriptstyle \beta_f} 
c_\ell^{\scriptscriptstyle \beta_\ell}
c_m^{\scriptscriptstyle \beta_m}$
\end{document}
```

specifically like this:

[image]

Not only are the vertical sizes non-uniform, but the horizontal gap between `c` and `f` is greater than between `c` and `\ell` and between `c` and `x`. Is there a way to produce output where the three lines of code produce uniform output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can adjust the sub and superscript parameters see

[What do different \fontdimen<num> mean](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88991/what-do-different-fontdimennum-mean/88993#88993)

for a full list

[image]

By increasing the default amount they are raised or lowered you can get them lining up, the values here just chosen by eye, the original values shown in the log are

```
3.62892pt
2.47217pt
```

With the modified file being

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\begin{document}
\sbox0{$x$}% force math to load

\typeout{\the\fontdimen14\textfont2}
\fontdimen14\textfont2=5pt

\typeout{\the\fontdimen17\textfont2}
\fontdimen17\textfont2=5pt

$q_\ell^{\scriptscriptstyle {\alpha}_{c\ell}}
 q_f^{\scriptscriptstyle {\alpha}_{cf}}
 q_x^{\scriptscriptstyle {\alpha}_{cx}}
$\\[12pt]
$ c_f^{\scriptscriptstyle \beta_f} 
c_\ell^{\scriptscriptstyle \beta_\ell}
c_m^{\scriptscriptstyle \beta_m}$


\bigskip


$q_\ell^{{\alpha}_{c\ell}}
 q_f^{{\alpha}_{cf}}
 q_x^{{\alpha}_{cx}}
$\\[12pt]
$ c_f^{\beta_f} 
c_\ell^{\beta_\ell}
c_m^{\beta_m}$

\end{document}
```

I also show the version with normal sized superscripts (which look better to me especially as they are themselves subscripted)

Answer (score 6):

You can use a number of `\vphantom`s, choosing the largest component - `f` - and `\vphantom{f}` with the other, smaller elements:

[image]

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\begin{document}

$q_\ell^{\scriptscriptstyle {\alpha}_{c\ell}}
 q_f^{\scriptscriptstyle {\alpha}_{cf}}
 q_x^{\scriptscriptstyle {\alpha}_{cx}}
$\quad
$q_{\vphantom{f}\ell}^{\alpha_{c\ell\vphantom{f}}}
 q_f^{\alpha_{cf}}
 q_{\vphantom{f}x}^{\alpha_{cx\vphantom{f}}}
$

\bigskip

$c_f^{\scriptscriptstyle \beta_f} 
c_\ell^{\scriptscriptstyle \beta_\ell}
c_m^{\scriptscriptstyle \beta_m}$\quad
$c_f^{\beta_f} 
c_{\vphantom{f}\ell}^{\beta_{\ell\vphantom{f}}}
c_{\vphantom{f}m}^{\beta_{m\vphantom{f}}}$

\end{document}
```

The spacing can be adjusted using any of the methods suggested in [What commands are there for horizontal spacing?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/74353/5764).

Comment: Thanks very much to both of you.    I accepted David's answer because it was simpler to implement.