# Different spacing of only superscript vs superscript and subscript + mathrm vs operatorname

Tags: math-mode, subscripts, superscripts, vertical-spacing, mathrm

I'd like to have superscript terms (gt) on the same line in the whole equation, but after I write the equation:

```
$\mathbf{T}^{\mathrm gt}=\{\mathbf{T}^{\mathrm gt}_1,\mathbf{T}^{\mathrm gt}_2,\ldots,\mathbf{T}^{\operatorname{gt}}_k\}$
```

I receive this:

[image: output]

I know I can add _{\phantom{1}} term, but it is not elegant as for equations without subscripts - I would have to add this phantom to be consistent in a whole document.
Also is there a need to use operatorname or simple mathrm is enough?

Comment: in `^{\mathrm gt}` did you intend to get an upright g and italic t? the markup `^{\mathrm {g}t}` would be clearer or `^{\mathrm{gt}}` if you want an upright`t` omitting braces from `\mathrm` isn't documented syntax  at all

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/576346/1090

Comment: The subscript k also seems to sit lower than the other subscripts. Or maybe that is just an illusion.

Comment: @mickep No illusion the k is put lower than the other subscripts for the presence of gt.

Comment: @David Carlisle Thank You for spotting this error -- I intended using \mathrm{gt}

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You *might* use `subdepth`. But I don't recommend it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{subdepth}

\newcommand{\gt}{\mathrm{gt}}

\begin{document}

\[
%%% the following two lines are just to show the alignment
\sbox0{$\displaystyle\mathbf{T}^{\gt}$}
\rlap{\vrule height \dimeval{\ht0+0.1pt} depth -\ht0 width 4cm}
%%%
\mathbf{T}^{\gt}=
  \{\mathbf{T}^{\gt}_1,\mathbf{T}^{\gt}_2,\ldots,\mathbf{T}^{\gt}_k\}
\]
\begin{center}
$%%% the following two lines are just to show the alignment
\sbox0{$\displaystyle\mathbf{T}^{\gt}$}
\rlap{\vrule height \dimeval{\ht0+0.1pt} depth -\ht0 width 4cm}
%%%
\mathbf{T}^{\gt}=
  \{\mathbf{T}^{\gt}_1,\mathbf{T}^{\gt}_2,\ldots,\mathbf{T}^{\gt}_k\}
$\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that `\mathrm gt` is wrong under any respect. Also `\operatorname` isn't good in that context.

---

If you have just a couple of these constructs, it's easier to add a few `\vphantom`.

For several instances of the same structure,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\tuple}{mm}
 {% #1 is the base symbol, #2 is the list of subscripts
  #1\sb{\vphantom{#2}} = \{
  \seq_clear:N \l_tmpa_seq
  \clist_map_inline:nn { #2 }
   {
    \str_if_eq:nnTF { ##1 } { \dots }
     {
      \seq_put_right:Nn \l_tmpa_seq { \dotsc }
     }
     {
      \seq_put_right:Nn \l_tmpa_seq { #1\sb{##1\vphantom{#2}} }
     }
   }
  \seq_use:Nn \l_tmpa_seq { , }
  \}
 }

\newcommand{\gt}{\mathrm{gt}}

\begin{document}

\[
\tuple{\mathbf{T}^{\gt}}{1,2,\dots,k}
\]
\begin{center}
$\tuple{\mathbf{T}^{\gt}}{1,2,\dots,k}$
\end{center}

\[
\tuple{A}{1,2,3} \quad \tuple{B}{1,2,3,\dots}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The subscript k still seems to sit lower than the 1 and the 2 subscripts.

Comment: @mickep Yes, because *k* is a bit higher than the digits; `\smash{k}` would do. But see the new code.

Comment: So basically, the best option is to use \vphantom? What is the reason of not using subdepth? Does it makes too many changes in the whole document? So I should use \mathrm{gt} with pharanthesis or just don't change the font at all?

Comment: @Wilk Did you look at the added code?

Comment: @egreg Yes I had. I just wanted to be sure. Thank You :)

Answer (score 2):

I think that this code is between the good solutions:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}

\begin{document}
$\mathbf{T}^{\substack{\mathrm{gt}}}_{\phantom{\substack{1}}}=\{\mathbf{T}^{\substack{\mathrm{gt}}}_{\substack{1}},\mathbf{T}^{\substack{\mathrm{gt}}}_{\substack{2}},\ldots,\mathbf{T}^{\substack{\mathrm{gt}}}_{\substack{k}}\}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: The superscripts aren't on the same line

Comment: Now the superscripts are on the same line.

Comment: Do remember that `\text` is the wrong command to use (its contents is italic in an italic context which is not what you want in this case)

Comment: @daleif I have corrected using \mathrm.

Comment: but I didn't wanted to use _{\phantom{1}}

Comment: @Wilk I known only this trick. I am sorry.