# Double subscript followed by superscript gives unpleasant result

Tags: equations, subscripts, superscripts

When typing

```
$C_{\mathscr T_{\nu^\dagger}}$ and $C_{\mathscr T_\nu}$
```

we get the output
[image]

The way in which $\nu$ is moved further down when introducing the $\dagger$ symbol is unsightly and I am wondering how this can be typeset to give something a little more compact and aesthetically pleasing.  I tried placing additional curly braces in various places to see if I got a better result but it did not change anything!

Edit: Here is a MWE

```
\documentclass[]{report}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}

\begin{document}
$C_{\mathscr T_{\nu^\dagger}}$ and $C_{\mathscr T_\nu}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: You could try replacing `\nu^\dagger` by `\nu^{\smash{\dagger}}`, but sub-sub-subscripts will never look good anyway, so I'd change notation `;-)`

Comment: @campa "but sub-sub-subscripts will never look good anyway"...sigh....I know you're right! At least \smash{} looks a lot better. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I am not generally a fan of making a symbol-style smaller than the `\scriptscriptstyle`, in this case, one can almost think of `\nu^\dag` as its own glyph.  So, what I do here is to define a `\nudagref` in `\textstyle` that has is essentially `\nu^\dag`, with the `\dag` smashed, so that it has the dimensions of `\nu`.  Then, when I want to use it in smaller math styles, I scale the `\nudagref` down to the size of `\nu` in the smaller math style.

In the MWE, the first line shows `\dag` and `\nudag` in all three styles.  Then I show what the OP had shown.  Finally, I employ `\nudag` in the final line.  One downside is that the nu of `\nudag` is a scaled `\textstyle` version, and thus has a slightly different shape than the smaller style `\nu`.  See **ALTERNATIVE** below for a correction to this issue.

```
\documentclass[]{report}
\usepackage{mathrsfs,scalerel}
\newcommand\nudagref{\textstyle\nu^{\mkern-1mu\smash{\dag}}}
\newcommand\nudag{\scalerel*{\nudagref}{\nu}}

\begin{document}
$\dag\nudag_{\nudag_{\nudag}}$

$C_{\mathscr T_{\nu^{\smash{\dagger}}}}$ vs $C_{\mathscr T_\nu}$

$C_{\mathscr T_{\nudag}}$ vs $C_{\mathscr T_\nu}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

**ALTERNATIVE:**

This version preserves the *proper* shape of the `\nu` in the smaller math styles.

```
\documentclass[]{report}
\usepackage{mathrsfs,scalerel}
\newcommand\dagref{\textstyle\vphantom{\nu}^{\mkern-1mu\smash{\dag}}}
\newcommand\nudag{\nu\scalerel*{\dagref}{\nu}}
\begin{document}
$\dag\nudag_{\nudag_{\nudag}}$

$C_{\mathscr T_{\nu^{\smash{\dagger}}}}$ vs $C_{\mathscr T_\nu}$

$C_{\mathscr T_{\nudag}}$ vs $C_{\mathscr T_{\nu}}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: "...one can almost think of \nu^\dag as its own glyph." I agree. I actually really like the \nudag command you made. One question. It looks like $\nu$ in the \nudag command has been squished a little in the horizontal direction. Can that be adjusted?

Comment: @AaronHendrickson That is the downside I speak of in the answer.  It is not that my symbol is squished in the smaller math style, but the opposite, that the smaller mathstyles horizontally stretch the glyph.  I will give some thought to an alternative, one of which would be to create an `\altnu` that also does not stretch.

Comment: @AaronHendrickson That would be `\newcommand\altnu{\scalerel*{\textstyle\nu}{\nu}}` and just use `\altnu` in the smaller styles.

Comment: @AaronHendrickson I provide an **ALTERNATIVE** version in my edit that succeeds at preserving the shape of the `\nu` in the smaller math styles.  I think you will find it preferable.  And thank you for the "accept"

Comment: The alternative is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

You can hide the symbols or try to adjust the default positioning to get more even spacing for the symbols you use.

[image]

```
\documentclass[]{report}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}

\begin{document}

$C_{\mathscr{T}_{\nu^\dagger}}$ and $C_{\mathscr{T}_\nu}$


$C_{\mathscr{T}_{\nu^{\smash{\dagger}}}}$ and $C_{\mathscr{T}_\nu}$


$C_{\mathscr{T}_{\nu^\dagger}}$ and $C_{\mathscr{T}_{\nu^{\vphantom{\dagger}}}}$


{% adjust as required.....
\fontdimen 12 \scriptfont2 =15pt
\fontdimen 13 \scriptfont2 =15pt
\fontdimen 14 \scriptfont2 =15pt
\fontdimen 15 \scriptfont2 =15pt

\fontdimen 16 \textfont2 =15pt
\fontdimen 17 \textfont2 =15pt
\fontdimen 18 \textfont2 =15pt
\fontdimen 19 \textfont2 =15pt

\fontdimen 16 \scriptfont2 =15pt
\fontdimen 17 \scriptfont2 =15pt
\fontdimen 18 \scriptfont2 =15pt
\fontdimen 19 \scriptfont2 =15pt

$C_{\mathscr{T}_{\nu^\dagger}}$ and $C_{\mathscr{T}_\nu}$
}

\end{document}
```

See

[What do different \fontdimen<num> mean](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88991/what-do-different-fontdimennum-mean/88993#88993)