# How to get automatic math superscript height like \dagger?

Tags: math-mode, superscripts

I wish to define a superscript that is adaptive to the height of the character before it.
Just like using the `\dagger` offered by latex.
For example, for the following code:

```
\[    
  \sqrt{p^\top \mathcal{E}_u^\top \, p^x \mathcal{E}_u^x \, {p^\dagger} \mathcal{E}_u^\dagger}
\]
```

I get the following result

[image]

Notice how the height of the superscript `\top` and `x` are the same for characters of different sizes, but the `\dagger` superscript is properly placed.
How can I get the similar behavior as `\dagger`?

Answer (score 3):

`\dagger` has no special rules here, it is just rather taller and deeper than the other symbols, and so with the default superscript raise in the (cramped) style in the sqrt, there would not be sufficient room for the subscript u so it is raised more. If you increase the amount subscripts are raised in cramped style you can see it acts the same as other characters.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[ \fontdimen15\textfont2=5pt  
  \sqrt{p^\top \mathcal{E}_u^\top \, p^x \mathcal{E}_u^x \, {p^\dagger} \mathcal{E}_u^\dagger}
\]

\end{document}
```

See

[What do different \fontdimen<num> mean](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88991/what-do-different-fontdimennum-mean/88993#88993)

Comment: This solves my doubt about the \dagger behaviour. It seems there is no simple way to automatically adjust superscript height then.