# width of a control space in relation to a quad, thin, medium, and thick spaces

Tags: math-mode, spacing, white-space, horizontal

In the majority of fonts such as Computer Modern, NewTX Math, or TeX Gyre Termes Math, how wide is the control space `\`  (visibly: `\␣`) in relation to the other math-mode space commands

- `\quad`,
- `\;`,
- `\>`, and
- `\,`?

That is, is it possible to sort the list “`\quad`, `\;`, `\>`, `\,`, `\␣`“ in a descending order universally or almost universally?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\`  is the same as an interword space so is
`\fontdimen2` `plus` `\fontdimen3` `minus` `\fontdimen4`
in the current font.

`\quad` is `\hskip 1em` so is
`\fontdimen6`
in the current font.

See [What do different \fontdimen<num> mean](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88991/what-do-different-fontdimennum-mean/88993#88993)

`\;` `\>` `\,` were originally math mode only, but now have similar defintions in text mode and are `\thickmuskip`, `\medmuskip` and `\thinmuskip` respectively which are set by the macro layer but in `mu` units so 1/18 em in the font assigned to `\fam2`

generally `\quad` is bigger than `\`  which is bigger than `\;` then `\>` then `\,`

Answer (score 2):

A concrete measurement for Computer Modern:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xfp}
\newlength{\tmplen}
\newlength{\controlspacelen}

\begin{document}

\settowidth{\controlspacelen}{\ }%
Widths of spaces in Computer Modern:
\begin{itemize}
  \item
  \verb|\quad|:
  \settowidth{\tmplen}{\quad}\the\tmplen~
  (\fpeval{round(\tmplen / \controlspacelen, 1)} control spaces)
  
  \item
  \verb|\ |:
  \settowidth{\tmplen}{\ }\the\tmplen~
  (1 control space)
  
  \item
  \verb|\;|:
  \settowidth{\tmplen}{\;}\the\tmplen~
  (\fpeval{round(\tmplen / \controlspacelen, 1)} control spaces)
  
  \item
  \verb|\>|:
  \settowidth{\tmplen}{\>}\the\tmplen~
  (\fpeval{round(\tmplen / \controlspacelen, 1)} control spaces)
  
  \item
  \verb|\,|:
  \settowidth{\tmplen}{\,}\the\tmplen~
  (\fpeval{round(\tmplen / \controlspacelen, 1)} control spaces)
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The control space in practice may stretch or shrink like an interword space, to ensure that all lines are the same length.  The value you show is the starting width, before the line is justified.  All other spaces listed are fixed width.

Comment: @barbarabeeton no  by default `\>` and `\;` are stretchy as well

Comment: @DavidCarlisle -- Thanks for the correction.  The real point of my comment, though, is that the value shown is the base width, and there can also be stretch (and maybe shrink), so the "final" width may be different.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Is there any reason for `\,` not being stretchy whereas `\>` and `\;` are stretchy?

Comment: @GeekestGeek Because one day in the late '70's Professor Knuth thought that looked about right.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Hm, I see. I guess that's why it has always been bothering me that I have to write stuff such as `\mskip 3mu plus1.5mu minus1.5mu` instead of `\,` for a pleasant typesetting result. What do you use yourself if you wish to have a stretchy version of `\,`?

Comment: you know I almost never use tex:-)  But espcially if not using the original computer modern fonts, I would have no qualms about redefining all three of the muskip  spaces to fit what I thought looked best. Note redefining `\thinmuskip` is better than adding a by hand space amount as the point about `\,`, `\>` and `\;`  is that they are exactly the spaces added by tex between atoms of various classes and `\!` is exactly the negative of `\,` @GeekestGeek

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks! So let's say you have `$A\cup B$`, how much space is added around the union symbol? I always thought it to be the same as `A\,{\cup}\,B`, i.e., `\,` to each side of ∪; any comment on this?

Comment: @GeekestGeek `\cup` is \mathbin`  so that is `\medmuskip` `\:` not`\,`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle  Thanks! I see what goes on with `\:` and `\>`: they are the same according to `latex.ltx`, defaulting to `\mskip+\medmuskip` in math mode (and to something else in text mode). I have to change my `\,{Bin}\,` to `\>{Bin}\>` now to make it look as Bin, for binary operations Bin. Any idea why `\:` has been introduced to LaTeX (in addition to `\>`, which is already there anyway)?

Comment: @GeekestGeek I see you asked a new question about that but it's not true to say `\>` is already in latex and `\:` added. It is just that latex has always defined two commands for that.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle You're right. I meant that `\>` is already there in TeX.

Comment: @GeekestGeek "already" isn't the right word to use though, a different fomat (plain tex)  has a command of that name, but latex doesn't input plain tex and tex itself does not define a primitive command of that name. `\:`, `\medspace` and `\>` commands are undefined until all three are defined in consecutive lines as `latex.ltx` is loaded while defining the latex format.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Got it. Thank you!!!