# how to insert DENSELY dashdotted line in math mode or equations?

Tags: tikz-pgf, math-mode, line

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,onecolumn]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{caption}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,fit,calc}

\begin{document}
\tikzstyle{every node}=[circle, draw, fill=black!100,
                       inner sep=0pt, minimum width=6pt]
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick,scale=0.8]%
\draw(0,0)node[label={[yshift=0cm]270:{$1$}}](1){};
\draw(0,4)node[label={[yshift=0cm]90:{$2$}}](2){};
\draw(4,4)node[label={[yshift=0cm]90:{$3$}}](3){};
\draw(4,0)node[label={[yshift=0cm]270:{$4$}}](4){};

\draw[->, line width=0.3mm, >=latex, shorten <= 0.2cm, shorten >= 0.15cm](1)--(2);
\draw[dashed, ->, line width=0.3mm, >=latex, shorten <= 0.2cm, shorten >= 0.15cm](2)--(3);
\draw[densely dotted,->, line width=0.3mm, >=latex, shorten <= 0.2cm, shorten >= 0.15cm](3)--(4);
\draw[densely dashdotdotted, ->, line width=0.3mm, >=latex, shorten <= 0.2cm, shorten >= 0.15cm](4)--(1);
\end{tikzpicture}
{\captionof{figure}{4 types of arcs.}}

In Figure 1, there are 4 types of arcs, namely the solid $<display Solid Line Here>$, dashed $<display Dashed Line Here>$, densely dotted $<display Densely Dotted Line Here>$, and densely dashdotdotted $<display Densely Dashdotdotted Line Here>$.
\noindent\par The best I can do is 
In Figure 1, there are 4 types of arcs, namely the solid $<display Solid Line Here>$, dashed $<--->$, densely dotted $<\cdots>$, and densely dashdotdotted $<display Densely Dashdotdotted Line Here>$
\end{document}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can insert TikZ pictures at almost arbitrary locations in your document. There is even the shorthand notation `\tikz...;` for inline pictures with a single path.

To get a nice centering on the line I used `baseline=-\the\fontdimen22\textfont2` which is the height at which operators will be centered in math mode. See also [What do different \fontdimen<num> mean](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88991/what-do-different-fontdimennum-mean)

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,onecolumn]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{caption}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,fit,calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[
    thick,
    scale=0.8,
    every node/.style={
      circle,
      draw,
      fill=black!100,
      inner sep=0pt,
      minimum width=6pt
    }]
    \draw(0,0)node[label={[yshift=0cm]270:{$1$}}](1){};
    \draw(0,4)node[label={[yshift=0cm]90:{$2$}}](2){};
    \draw(4,4)node[label={[yshift=0cm]90:{$3$}}](3){};
    \draw(4,0)node[label={[yshift=0cm]270:{$4$}}](4){};
    
    \draw[->, line width=0.3mm, >=latex, shorten <= 0.2cm, shorten >= 0.15cm](1)--(2);
    \draw[dashed, ->, line width=0.3mm, >=latex, shorten <= 0.2cm, shorten >= 0.15cm](2)--(3);
    \draw[densely dotted,->, line width=0.3mm, >=latex, shorten <= 0.2cm, shorten >= 0.15cm](3)--(4);
    \draw[densely dashdotdotted, ->, line width=0.3mm, >=latex, shorten <= 0.2cm, shorten >= 0.15cm](4)--(1);
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \captionof{figure}{\label{fig:arcs}4 types of arcs.}
\end{center}

\newcommand*\lineexample[1]{%
  #1~(\tikz[baseline=-\the\fontdimen22\textfont2]\draw[#1](0,0)--(1.618em,0);)%
}

In Figure~\ref{fig:arcs}, there are 4 types of arcs, namely the
\lineexample{solid}, \lineexample{dashed}, \lineexample{densely dotted}, and
\lineexample{densely dashdotdotted}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Just for fun, here is the same example again with `\graph`.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,onecolumn]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}[
    thick,
    scale=0.8,
    every node/.style={
      circle,
      draw,
      fill=black!100,
      inner sep=0pt,
      minimum width=6pt
    }]

    \node[label={below:$1$}](1) at (0,0) {};
    \node[label={above:$2$}](2) at (0,4) {};
    \node[label={above:$3$}](3) at (4,4) {};
    \node[label={below:$4$}](4) at (4,0) {};

    \graph [use existing nodes,edges={>=latex,shorten <=0.2cm,shorten >=0.15cm}] {
      1 ->[solid] 2 ->[dashed] 3 ->[densely dotted] 4 ->[densely dashdotted] 1
    };
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \caption{\label{fig:arcs}4 types of arcs.}
\end{figure}

\newcommand*\lineexample[1]{%
  #1~(\tikz[baseline=-\the\fontdimen22\textfont2]\draw[#1](0,0)--(1.618em,0);)%
}

In Figure~\ref{fig:arcs}, there are 4 types of arcs, namely the
\lineexample{solid}, \lineexample{dashed}, \lineexample{densely dotted}, and
\lineexample{densely dashdotted}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: The densely dashdotted line looks different; I'm afraid it confuses the reader further. Is it possible to make it exactly the same as the picture? And you mentioned "You can insert TikZ pictures at almost arbitrary locations in your document. There is even the shorthand notation \tikz...; for inline pictures with a single path." Have you done this already?
Thank you

Comment: @SphericalMoments I misspelled the line type. I typed `densely dashdotted` instead of `densely dashdotdotted`. After fixing that it looks the same.

Comment: ok thank you. Can we omit the words "densely dashdotdotted", as I meant to type them in manually? So, the command would only show the lines within brackets but no words at all.

Comment: In the command `\lineexample`, you can see `#1~` at the beginning. This is what types the name of the dash type. If you just want the lines but not the names, delete this part.

Comment: ok thank you very much