# Limit interword shrinking without affecting the normal interword spacing

Tags: spacing, tex-core

There are many questions about interword spacing in Latex, but this question is different. I'm generally OK with the default spacing and do not want to change it. However, sometimes Latex shortens the interword spacing too much, making the text line very compressed. My guess is that there must be some threshold for how much the normal interword space can be reduced, and I would like to change just this threshold, without affecting anything else.

For example, I set the threshold to 2pt. Then I expect that for each pair of consecutive words with a distance of more than 2 points, this distance will not change, and for each pair of consecutive words with a distance of less than 2 points, this distance will increase to 2 points.

Is it possible?

Comment: I think that `\fontdimen4\font=0pt` will limit the shrinkage to 0pt

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Ok, thank you. However, I do not want to remove shrinkage at all; it is necessary in many cases. I just want to tune it a little to avoid cases of too much compressed text.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes And the tuning must be relative to the default value.

Comment: I have edited my answer to address the issue of relative change of fontdimen4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The amount of shrinkability is defined by the font metrics of the current font. Its value can be retrieved as `\fontdimen4\font` and it should be compared to the standard interword space, residing in `\fontdimen2\font`. The standard Computer Modern Roman font at 10pt has

`\fontdimen 2 = 3.33333pt`
`\fontdimen 4 = 1.11111pt`

whereas the NewTX font (a clone of Times) has

`\fontdimen 2 = 2.5pt`
`\fontdimen 4 = 1.00006pt`

so the interword space can shrink up to 1.5pt. By contrast, TeX Gyre Bonum, which is quite a wide font has

`\fontdimen 2 = 3.2pt`
`\fontdimen 4 = 1.06999pt`

There is no “universal threshold”: the font designer decides.

You can change the value of the relevant `\fontdimen`, but there are some points to be considered:

1. any assignment to a `\fontdimen` is global;
2. assigning a different `\fontdimen` must be done for every font variant (shape, weight or size) you use.

So, if you do

```
\AtBeginDocument{\fontdimen4\font=1pt }
```

this would only affect the `\normalfont` at `\normalsize`. You might hook into `\selectfont` for setting `\fontdimen4\font` to, say, one third of `\fontdimen2\font`, but this would also act on the monospaced fonts that, usually, have zero shrinkability.

Example.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{newtx}

\AddToHook{selectfont}{%
  \ifdim\fontdimen4\font>0pt
    \fontdimen4\font=\dimexpr\fontdimen2\font/3\relax
  \fi
}

\begin{document}

2: \the\fontdimen2\font

4: \the\fontdimen4\font

\itshape

2: \the\fontdimen2\font

4: \the\fontdimen4\font

\upshape\Large

2: \the\fontdimen2\font

4: \the\fontdimen4\font

\ttfamily

2: \the\fontdimen2\font

4: \the\fontdimen4\font

\end{document}
```

[image]

Without the `\AddToHook` declaration, the same code would produce

[image]

Comment: Two additional things to consider: (1) Is this affected by `microtype`? (2) For a letter with an overhang (like "f"), that would still extend into the interword space, but can be overcome by an italic correction (`\/`).  Italic correction is applied automatically if `\textit` or `\emph` is used, but not for a transition from italic to upright when only `\itshape` is used.  (An explicit italic correction may be desirable even in an all-upright environment with a juxtaposition like "of W" if the line is set tight.)

Comment: @egreg Thank you, your answer is closest to what i wanted.

Answer (score 1):

**REVISED ANSWER**

My original answer still provides useful information so I leave it below.  However, the OP, in revising the question would seem to like to specify the default interword space (`\fontdimen2`), would like there to be zero interword contraction below the threshold (`\fontdimen4`).  It is unclear if the OP wishes to specify the amount of allowable expansion of the interword space (`\fontdimen3`).

These may be set to achieve the OP's aims, in the following manner:

```
\fontdimen2\font=2pt% What the OP calls "Threshold"
\fontdimen3\font=22pt% allowable expansion beyond "Threshold"
\fontdimen4\font=0pt% Space will never shrink below threshold
```

See the accepted answer at [What do different \fontdimen<num> mean](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88991/what-do-different-fontdimennum-mean) for more details.

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

Shrinkage can potentially occur any time that the nominal width of the characters on a [full] line does not match the line width.  At that point, when typesetting the paragraph, TeX will either expand or shrink gluey dimensions in an effort to both match the linewidth while maximizing the "quality" algorithm, which it does through a series of user-settable penalties.

Commands like `\sloppy` are merely a reset of certain penalties used by the quality-algorithm.

The current value of `\fontdimen4` may be seen with `\the\fontdimen4\font`.  Its value may be changed in a relative way with

```
\fontdimen4\font=\dimexpr\fontdimen4\font-1pt\relax
```

In all 3 cases below, the line exceeds the textwidth given by the rule.  However, the amount of allowable shrinkage varies based on the setting of `\fontdimen4`.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\textwidth=.95in

\begin{document}

\noindent\rule{\textwidth}{2pt}

Test of spacing 

\fontdimen4\font=0pt
Test of spacing 

\fontdimen4\font=3pt
Test of spacing 
\end{document}
```

[image]

When there is no requirement for shrinkage, as when the `\textwidth` is set to 2in, all 3 cases are indistinguishable.  Also shown is how to change `\fontdimen4` relative to its current value.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\textwidth=2in

\begin{document}

\noindent\rule{\textwidth}{2pt}

Test of spacing 

\fontdimen4\font=0pt
Test of spacing 

\fontdimen4\font=3pt
Test of spacing 

Value of fontdimen4:
\the\fontdimen4\font

Changing its relative value:
\fontdimen4\font=\dimexpr\fontdimen4\font-1pt\relax
\the\fontdimen4\font

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Steven. I tried your answer, but unfortunately it is not what I wanted. It affects the space between EVERY two consecutive  words, while I only want to fix the space that is less than the threshold. Perhaps the wording of my question was not clear enough, and I edited it.

Comment: @Ilia My revised answer should provide what you need.  Only reset `\fontdimen3` if you want to specify the allowable expansion.