# Is there a package or a macro that allows to position the indices lower?

Tags: packages

The position of the indices is in my opinion located by default too high with LaTeX.
I found on the French site how to position them lower, but it remains heavy to write.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[a4paper,hmargin=15mm,top=18mm,bottom=20mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
% from https://texnique.fr/osqa/questions/8927/maths-descendre-un-indice-encore-plus-bas


\[ \text{ \textit{too high index:} } r_1 \qquad  \text{\textit{ well placed index:} }
r_{{}_{\mkern-2mu\scriptstyle1}}
\]

\[ r_1 \qquad
r_{{}_{\mkern-2mu\scriptstyle1}}
\]
\end{document}
```

What produces:

[image: screenshot]

Is there a package or a macro that allows to replace the native position of the indices by placing them lower (and this without changing the syntax of the indices)?

Comment: This is controlled by `\fontdimen` of font family 2, see [What do different \fontdimen<num> mean](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/88991) and an exact example of subscript lowering in `texdoc texbytopic`, sec. 23.10.3.

Comment: Try `\usepackage[low-sup]{subdepth}`. Or usw `$r^{}_{1}$`

Comment: @Zarko Thank you for your interest in this question. Unless I am mistaken, your code does not position the indices lower!

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ Thank you for your interest in this question. Can you elaborate on your comment, I don't quite understand its relation to my question.

Comment: Do you compare position of indices with use of packages and without it? Didn't see any difference?

Comment: @Zarko yes, I added this package in the declaration.

Answer (score 1):

```tex
\documentclass[11pt]{article} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[a4paper,hmargin=15mm,top=18mm,bottom=20mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{color, graphicx}

\begin{document}
\setbox0=\hbox{$.$} % init math font
\parindent=0pt

Subscript attributes: minimum shift down, from the main baseline, of the baseline of a subscript,
\begin{enumerate}
  \item sub1: when no superscript is present,
  \item sub2: when a superscript is present.
\end{enumerate}

Default: sub1 = \the\fontdimen16\textfont2, sub2 = \the\fontdimen17\textfont2
\newbox\subNoSup
\newbox\subSup
\setbox\subNoSup=\hbox{$A_{\rlap{\color{red}\rule{6em}{.4pt}}1}r_1$}
\setbox\subSup  =\hbox{$A^n_{\rlap{\color{blue}\rule{6em}{.4pt}}1} r^n_1$}

\[ A_1r_1, A^n_1 r^n_1 \]

Enlarge both by 2mu (1/9em)
\fontdimen16\textfont2=\dimexpr\fontdimen16\textfont2 + 1em/9\relax % 2mu = 1em/9
\fontdimen17\textfont2=\dimexpr\fontdimen17\textfont2 + 1em/9\relax

\[ A_1r_1, A^n_1 r^n_1 \]

Comparison:\par
\centering
\scalebox{3}{\parbox{7em}{
  \leavevmode\copy\subNoSup \qquad $A_1 r_1$ \par
  \leavevmode\copy\subSup   \qquad $A^n_1 r^n_1$
}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: this is interesting, but will this modify other parameters of LaTeX or only the indexes and therefore have no influence elsewhere on the document?

Comment: @AndréC I don't know too much about font dimensions. Lowering subscripts too much will enlarge the resulting baselineskip, as I guess. Also I find font size switches will reset font dimensions, maybe due to optimal sizes.