# Scansion Bars Between Syllables in Poetry

Tags: poetry

To put faint, non-kerning lines between syllables, is there a way for the command to detect if it is adjacent to a space and if so to (a) restore the space, and (b) place the bar midway?  (Alternately, user could place \m between spaces, like `to be, \m or not \m to be`, in which case code should detect that and back up half a space to place bar.)

PSEUDOCODE:

Am I adjacent to a space?

- Y: restore the space (that I have destroyed by coming before it and being a command), and place bar in the middle of that space
- N: place bar between letters without impacting letter spacing

  ```
   \documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}
   \usepackage{xcolor}

   \newcommand\m{%
    {%
     \color{gray!50}%
     \rule[-\dp\strutbox]{0.3pt}%
     {\baselineskip}%
    }%
   }%

   \begin{document}

   \noindent To be,\m or not\m to be,\m that is\m the question:\\
   Whether\m 'tis nob\m ler in\m the mind\m to suffer\\
   The slings\m and ar\m rows of\m outrage\m ous fortune,\\
   Or to\m take arms\m against\m a sea\m of troubles

   \end{document}
  ```

Comment: you can test for a space but there is no space after `\m` it would be easier to use a syntax such as `|`  so `To be,| or not| to be`  and `nob|ler` then the space is tokenised (or not)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle my goal is to have the spacing of the original line remain unchanged by the placement of these faint bars.

Comment: yes but do you really need `\m`  it would be much easier to use | (which you still define to be the grey rule). Also what to you mean by unchanged do you want `nob|ler` the same width as `nobler` with the rule over-printing the `bl` slightly, or do you want `nob|ler`  to be wider by the width of the rule?

Comment: You could also consider making `|` an active character and define it as whatever kind of vertical rule you want.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle oh no, I definitely do not need `\m`!  Oooo, I like the idea of "wider by the width of the rule", both for words and inter-word spaces.

Comment: @Gaussler (also to David Carlisle): I confess I was unaware one could embed a command inside a single character.

Comment: @commonhare Simply do ```\catcode`|=\active``` and then `\def|{<whatever you want>}`.

Comment: @Gaussler yes exactly, that's what I meant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

```
 \documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}
 \usepackage{xcolor}
\makeatletter
% just do this locally if you need | for tables or tikz etc
\catcode`\|\active 
 \newcommand|{\futurelet\poetry@tmp\poetry@bar}

\newcommand\poetry@bar{%
    \ifhmode\unskip\fi
    \ifx\poetry@tmp\@sptoken
     % half word space see
     % https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88991/what-do-different-fontdimennum-mean/
     \hskip.5\fontdimen2\font\@plus.5\fontdimen3\font\@minus.5\fontdimen4\font
    \fi
   {\color{gray!50}%
   \rule[-\dp\strutbox]{0.3pt}%
   {\baselineskip}}%
       \ifx\poetry@tmp X\fi
    \ifx\poetry@tmp\@sptoken
     % half word space
     \hskip.5\fontdimen2\font\@plus.5\fontdimen3\font\@minus.5\fontdimen4\font
    \fi
   \ignorespaces
}  

\makeatother
 \begin{document}
\setlength\parskip{0pt}

 To be,| or not| to be,| that is| the question:\\
 Whether| 'tis nob|ler in| the mind| to suffer\\
 The slings| and ar|rows of| outrage|ous fortune,\\
 Or to| take arms| against| a sea| of troubles

 \end{document}
```

`|` is easier to input than `\m` and avoids losing the space, so you can test for a space with `\futurelet`