# How do you make whitespace the afterskip of a runin subsubsection in KOMA script?

Tags: spacing, sectioning, formatting, koma-script

I want to set my afterskip so that after the title there would be a whitespace seperating the title and the paragraph. I'm using KOMA-script.

Minimum working example:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
% Specifying titles
\RedeclareSectionCommand[runin=true,afterskip=%\ ?]{subsubsection}
\begin{document}
\subsubsection{Phụ âm đầu}
là bộ phận phụ khởi đầu của một âm tiết trừ đi phần vần và thanh điệu.
\end{document}
```

Edit: the whitespace i'm asking this the space between two letters like this: "**Phụ âm đầu** là bộ phận phụ"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

The key takes a length you can include stretch and shrink components so that the white space helps justify the line

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
% Specifying titles

\RedeclareSectionCommand[runin=true,afterskip=2cm plus 1cm minus 1cm ]{subsubsection}
\begin{document}
\subsubsection{Phụ âm đầu}
là bộ phận phụ khởi đầu của một âm tiết trừ đi phần vần và thanh điệu.
\end{document}
```

If you want a normal word space use the fontdimens

[What do different \fontdimen<num> mean](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88991/what-do-different-fontdimennum-mean/88993#88993)

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
% Specifying titles

\RedeclareSectionCommand[runin=true,afterskip=\glueexpr
\fontdimen2\font
plus \fontdimen3\font
minus \fontdimen4\font
\relax
 ]{subsubsection}
\begin{document}
\subsubsection{Phụ âm đầu}
là bộ phận phụ khởi đầu của một âm tiết trừ đi phần vần và thanh điệu.
\end{document}
```

(I do not think `\glueexpr` should be needed, but the option parser gets confused without it)

---

It is horizontal space as you have a run-in heading, with runin false it is vertical space

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
% Specifying titles

\RedeclareSectionCommand[runin=false,afterskip=2cm plus 1cm minus 1cm ]{subsubsection}
\begin{document}
\subsubsection{Phụ âm đầu}
là bộ phận phụ khởi đầu của một âm tiết trừ đi phần vần và thanh điệu.
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but what I need is whitespace as in the space that is used between words. Your question doesn't really answer my question. I need it to be like this "**Phụ âm đầu** là bộ phận"

Comment: @AdrikIvanov I would _never_ have guessed you meant that from your question. You just need to use the first form with the correct length, I'll add a note with the value.

Comment: @AdrikIvanov better now?

Comment: Yes. Thank you.