# Large vertical spacing in denominator above \rho

Tags: fractions, vertical-spacing

The vertical spacing above rho in the denominator here is off. I'm not sure if it's caused by the descender in the numerator, or if that only exaggerates the issue. I think both 2/μ and μ/2 look alright, but I'm not a typographer. How can I make it look proper?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  \sqrt{\frac2\rho} + \sqrt{\frac\mu\rho} + \sqrt{\frac\mu2}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: rho is kind of small but the design is such that normal fractions all have a standard minimum size even if empty `\frac{1}{2}` and `\frac{1}{}` are the same height even though it is all space in the denominator, you see the same in the numerator where the reason for the gap under 2 is  to allow y or \mu on the same baseline. So it looks as intended now, I would not change it.

Comment: Thanks @DavidCarlisle. What can I do to make it look good, except for `\rho^{-1}`?

Comment: retrain your expectations then what you show will look good. If you reduce the gap by raising rho or lowering the bar of the fraction, the formula as a whole will look inconsistent and a mess.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I just included this sum to compare the fractions, my actual equation is very simple: `c_\text{sh}=\sqrt{\frac\mu\rho}`. Do you think adjusting the spacing would make it look like an inconsistent mess even when there's just a single fraction?

Comment: I wouldn't change it, you see the problem everywhere baselines of paragraphs are spaced to allow accented capital letters so if you have no accents or all lowercase it's often bigger than needed, but you don't want different baselines for different paragraphs, but if a document is almost all lowercase you may squeeze the spacing a bit  even if it makes capital letters look very tight  the spacing for the denominator is fontdimen11 https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88991/what-do-different-fontdimennum-mean/88993#88993 you could experiment with it but....

Comment: Well, I'd say the middle fraction looks bad. Do you agree that it looks bad but that I should not hope for better with LaTeX, or that it looks good? I also didn't quite understand your response, maybe I was unclear. This is a single display equation. I don't want to change the look of anything else in my document.

Comment: I guess it is the small height of the `\mu` in the numerator that in combination with the large depth of the `\rho` that causes this. Maybe you want `\sqrt{\frac{\vphantom{2}\mu}{\rho}}`? (Since you seem to be fine with the left version.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the OP's code, the three square root symbols don't have the same height (and depth too, for that matter). IMNSHO, the sum would look a whole lot better if the three square root symbols had the same size. I suggest you change of numerator of the middle term from `\mu` to `\mu\vphantom{2}`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\[
\sqrt{\frac{2}{\rho}} + \sqrt{\frac{\mu}{\rho}} + \sqrt{\frac{\mu}{2}}
\quad{\mbox{vs.}}\quad
\sqrt{\frac{2}{\rho}} + \sqrt{\frac{\mu\vphantom{2}}{\rho}} + \sqrt{\frac{\mu}{2}}
\]
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*: The OP has provided a comment with information about the "real" expression of interest, *viz.*, `c_\text{sh}=\sqrt{\frac\mu\rho}`, and has asked what kind of placement corrections (if any) I'd apply to this expression.

- My main recommendation would be to switch from `\frac` notation to inline-fraction notation, i.e., to write `\sqrt{\mu/\rho}`. This works especially well because `\mu` and `\rho` happen to have the same height and depth.
- If `\frac` notation cannot be avoided, I'd say that it's the vertical placement of the square root symbol that's the real issue here, rather than the placement of the denominator term in the fraction. Compare `\sqrt{\frac{\mu}{\rho}}` against `\sqrt{\frac{\mu}{\smash[b]{\rho}}}`: IMNSHO, the latter expression looks better because while the tall square root symbols have the same overall size in both cases, the square root symbols is placed a bit higher in the latter case, leading to better overall proportions.

Oh, and I'd write `c_{\mathrm{sh}}` rather than `c_{\text{sh}}`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for \smash[b] macro
\begin{document}
\[
c_{\mathrm{sh}}=\sqrt{\frac{\mu}{\rho}}
               =\sqrt{\frac{\mu}{\smash[b]{\rho}}}
               =\sqrt{\mu/\rho}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! In fact, I used the sum only for comparison -- apologies for not putting my actual case in the question, which is simpler: `c_\text{sh}=\sqrt{\frac\mu\rho}`. Would you adjust the spacing in that case?

Comment: @Anna - Please see the addendum I just posted.

Comment: Thank you @Mico! Can I just ask, what is the reason to prefer mathrm?

Comment: @Anna \text is italic in an italic context, mathrm is always upright. And assuming that `_\text` always works is also bad

Answer (score 4):

You can raise the \rho, but I wouldn't. making one isolated term look "better" at the expense of losing consistent baselines is not usually a good trade, but...

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  \sqrt{\frac{2}{\rho}} +
  \sqrt{\frac{\mu}{\rho}} +
  \sqrt{\frac{\mu}{\raisebox{2pt}[0pt]{$\rho$}}} +
  \sqrt{\frac{\mu}{2}}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```