# Are the space and the control space different with respect to stretch and shrink?

Tags: spacing, white-space, glue, horizontal-spacing

Feeding

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\showoutput
\begin{document}\noindent
A B\\
A\ B\\
A\hskip\fontdimen2\font plus\fontdimen3\font minus\fontdimen4\font B
\end{document}
```

to `latex` yields thrice the same “A B” in the DVI file without any visible difference. However, the stretch and shrink values in the console output do differ:

```
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 A
....\glue 3.33333 plus 1.66498 minus 1.11221
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 B
....\penalty 10000
....\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil
....\penalty -10000
....\glue(\rightskip) 0.0
...\penalty 150
...\glue(\baselineskip) 5.16669
...\hbox(6.83331+0.0)x345.0, glue set 327.0833fil
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 A
....\glue 3.33333 plus 1.66666 minus 1.11111
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 B
....\penalty 10000
....\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil
....\penalty -10000
....\glue(\rightskip) 0.0
...\penalty 150
...\glue(\baselineskip) 5.16669
...\hbox(6.83331+0.0)x345.0, glue set 327.0833fil
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 A
....\glue 3.33333 plus 1.66666 minus 1.11111
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 B
```

The difference is slight (`plus 1.66498 minus 1.11221` in the first line vs. `plus 1.66666 minus 1.11111` in the second and third lines), but it still exists. Why does this happen? Following *The TeXbook*, I thought that `\`  is how we typeset a usual space   after a command (say, `\foo\`  vs. `\foo` ), without any difference in the semantics, but apparently, I was wrong on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The space added by   is the space specified by the font dimens adjusted by `\spacefactor`, specifically the `plus` component is multiplied by `\spacefactor/1000` as `\spacefactor` is usually 1000 but is 999 after a capital letter so the values differ by a factor of 999/1000 as `\`  is not affected by `\spacefactor` and always adds a standard word space even after punctuation (or capital letters).
The `minus` component is similar but multiplied by `1000/\spacefactor`

```
\documentclass{article}
\showoutput
\begin{document}\noindent
A B\\
A\ B\\
A\hskip\fontdimen2\font plus\fontdimen3\font minus\fontdimen4\font B\\
A\dimen0=\fontdimen3\font
\multiply\dimen0 \spacefactor % = 999 not 1000
\divide\dimen0 1000
\dimen2=\fontdimen4\font
\multiply\dimen2 1000
\divide\dimen2 \spacefactor
A\hskip\fontdimen2\font plus\dimen0 minus\dimen2 B

a\showthe\spacefactor  A\showthe\spacefactor 
\end{document}
```

This shows the four glue settings as

```
....\glue 3.33333 plus 1.66498 minus 1.11221
....\glue 3.33333 plus 1.66666 minus 1.11111
....\glue 3.33333 plus 1.66666 minus 1.11111
....\glue 3.33333 plus 1.66498 minus 1.11221
```

showing the last line calculation matches the   glue.

Comment: I see. I completely missed the fact that the letters were capital. Right! With “a b” instead, this artefact doesn't happen.