Change height of superscripts and depth of subscripts
How do I change the height of the superscripts (to make them higher) and the depth of the subscripts (to make them lower) in math mode formulas in LaTeX? For the subscripts I have tried the following code:
$
\fontdimen16\textfont2=5pt
\fontdimen17\textfont2=5pt
$

but only some subscripts have changed, not all.
I guess I discovered what is hapenning, however I don´t know how to avoid it. The problem is that inside an environment ("exemplo") the changes are not applied (they are applied on the outside however). How can I make the changes apply everywhere (inside and outisde environments)? I prepared the MWE:
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[a4,center,cam,dvips,noinfo]{crop}
\usepackage [brazilian] {babel}
\usepackage [utf8] {inputenc}
\usepackage [T1] {fontenc}
\usepackage {amsfonts}          
\usepackage {amsmath,amssymb,latexsym}
\usepackage {ntheorem}

\newcommand {\vtr} {\vartriangleright}
\newcommand{\destaque}[1]{\textbf{#1}}
\newtheorem {Ex} {\small\rmfamily\upshape$\!$Exemplo} [chapter]
\newenvironment{exemplo}
{
\begin{Ex}
\small
\rmfamily
\upshape
}
{\hspace*{\fill}$\star\star\star$
\end{Ex}
}  

\begin {document}
$
\fontdimen14\textfont2=4pt
\fontdimen15\textfont2=4pt
\fontdimen16\textfont2=10pt
\fontdimen17\textfont2=10pt
$
\section {Igualdade-$\beta$}

Um termo $P$ é dito \destaque{$\beta$-igual} ou \destaque {$\beta$- 
conversível} a um termo $Q$, denotado $P =_{\beta} Q$, se e somente se 
$Q$ puder ser obtido a partir de $P$ por uma sequência finita 
(eventualmente vazia) de contrações-$\beta$, contrações-$\beta$ 
reversas e mudanças de variáveis ligadas. Ou seja, $P =_{\beta} Q$ se e 
somente se existir $P_0, ..., P_n (n\geq 0)$ tal que: $$(\forall i \leq 
n-1), (P_i \vtr_{1\beta} P_{i+1}) \mbox {\ ou\ } (P_{i+1} \vtr_{1\beta} 
P_i) \mbox {\ ou\ } (P_i \equiv_{\alpha} P_{i+1}),$$ $$P_0 \equiv P,$$ 
$$P_n \equiv Q.$$

\begin {exemplo}
Sejam $P\equiv (\lambda xyz.xzy)(\lambda xy.x)$ e $Q\equiv (\lambda 
xy.x)(\lambda x.x)$. Então $P=_{\beta}Q$, ou seja:
$$(\lambda xyz.xzy)(\lambda xy.x) =_{\beta} (\lambda xy.x)(\lambda 
x.x)$$

De fato, pode-se notar inicialmente que:
\begin {eqnarray*}
(\lambda xyz.xzy)(\lambda xy.x) & \equiv_{\alpha} & (\lambda xyz.xzy) 
(\lambda uv.u) \\
                            & \vtr_{1\beta}   & \lambda yz.(\lambda 
uv.u)zy \\
                            & \vtr_{1\beta}   & \lambda yz.(\lambda 
v.z)y \\
                            & \vtr_{1\beta}   & \lambda yz.z
\end {eqnarray*}                                
Além disso, que:
\begin {eqnarray*}
(\lambda xy.x)(\lambda x.x) & \equiv_{\alpha} & (\lambda xy.x)(\lambda 
w.w) \\
                        & \vtr_{1\beta}   & \lambda y.(\lambda w.w) \\
                        & \equiv          & \lambda yw.w \\
                        & \equiv_{\alpha} & \lambda yz.z
\end {eqnarray*}                                
Finalmente, pode-se considerar $P_0,P_1,P_2,P_3,P_4,P_5,P_6,P_7$ tais 
que:
\begin {eqnarray*}
P = P_0 & = & (\lambda xyz.xzy)(\lambda xy.x) \\
P_1 & = & (\lambda xyz.xzy)(\lambda uv.u) \\
P_2 & = & \lambda yz.(\lambda uv.u)zy \\
P_3 & = & \lambda yz.(\lambda v.z)y \\
P_4 & = & \lambda yz.z \\
P_5 & = & \lambda yw.w \\
P_6 & = & (\lambda xy.x)(\lambda w.w) \\
Q = P_7 & = & (\lambda xy.x)(\lambda x.x)
\end {eqnarray*}
Para concluir que $P=_{\beta}Q$, basta observar que $P_0 
\equiv_{\alpha} P_1$, $P_1 \vtr_{1\beta} P_2$, $P_2 \vtr_{1\beta} P_3$, 
$P_3 \vtr_{1\beta} P_4$, $P_4 \equiv_{\alpha} P_5$, $P_6 \vtr_{1\beta} 
P_5$ e $P_6 \equiv_{\alpha} P_7$.
\end {exemplo}
\end {document}

Thanks in advance,
Marcus.
P.S.
What I did was to create a new command:
\newcommand{\setsubsuperscripts}{
$
\fontdimen14\textfont2=4pt
\fontdimen15\textfont2=4pt
\fontdimen16\textfont2=4pt
\fontdimen17\textfont2=4pt
$
}

and use it after \begin{document} (for global changes) and in each environment, since this command does not affect new environments.
That works, but I would prefer use the command only once and have its effects spread the whole document, including the new environments.

Not really. It simply says that I should use the commands that I am already using.

In this case, you should provide a minimal working example (MWE) .

OK, I´ll make one,

I guess I discovered what is hapenning, however I don´t know how to avoid it. The problem is that inside an environment ("exemplo") the changes are not applied (they are applied on the outside however). How can I make the changes apply everywhere (inside and outisde environments)? My original post has been updated with a MWE.

if you change the settings inside $...$ the settings will be discarded at the end of that math expression.  Remove the $ as your settings will have no effect at all in an empty math list. Also all of parameters 13-19 affect this not just 16-17 see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88991/what-do-different-fontdimennum-mean/88993#88993

Finally I managed to insert the MWE.

$ \fontdimen14\textfont2=4pt \fontdimen15\textfont2=4pt \fontdimen16\textfont2=10pt \fontdimen17\textfont2=10pt $  does nothing at all as you have set them all within a group so all the settings are discarded at the second $.  Remove the $ (and move all the settings to just after \begin{document})

If I do so (remove both $ and place the code right after \begin{document}), I get an error message: "! Font \nullfont has only 7 fontdimen parameters."

you should not put the solution into the question but initialise the math first with (say) \sbox0{$ $} then set the parameters, note you shoudl not use $$ in latex so all teh $$ should be \[..\] (but that is unrelated) and you should use align* rather than eqnarray*

Assignments to \fontdimen are global.
What happens with your code is that the changes you do at the beginning are valid for \normalsize, but \small uses a different \textfont2, whose \fontdimens would be unaffected.
You can decide what value you want to use in \normalsize and \small (and possibly with other font sizes) and set them at begin document producing an empty formula in each of the sizes.
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[a4,center,cam,noinfo]{crop}
\usepackage [brazilian] {babel}
\usepackage [utf8] {inputenc}
\usepackage [T1] {fontenc}
\usepackage {amsfonts}          
\usepackage {amsmath,amssymb,latexsym}
\usepackage {ntheorem}

\newcommand{\vtr}{\vartriangleright}
\newcommand{\destaque}[1]{\textbf{#1}}

\theoremheaderfont{\small\normalfont\bfseries}
\theorembodyfont{\small\normalfont}
\newtheorem{exemplo}{Exemplo}[chapter]

% fix the values, these are wrong
\newcommand{\normalsizesubscripts}{%
  \fontdimen14\textfont2=4pt
  \fontdimen15\textfont2=4pt
  \fontdimen16\textfont2=10pt
  \fontdimen17\textfont2=10pt
}
\newcommand{\smallsubscripts}{%
  \fontdimen14\textfont2=4pt
  \fontdimen15\textfont2=4pt
  \fontdimen16\textfont2=10pt
  \fontdimen17\textfont2=10pt
}
% do the settings
\AtBeginDocument{\sbox0{$\normalsizesubscripts$\small$\smallsubscripts$}}

\begin{document}

\section{Igualdade-$\beta$}

Um termo $P$ é dito \destaque{$\beta$-igual} ou \destaque{$\beta$-conversível}
a um termo $Q$, denotado $P =_{\beta} Q$, se e somente se 
$Q$ puder ser obtido a partir de $P$ por uma sequência finita 
(eventualmente vazia) de contrações-$\beta$, contrações-$\beta$ 
reversas e mudanças de variáveis ligadas. Ou seja, $P =_{\beta} Q$ se e 
somente se existir $P_0,\dots, P_n (n\geq 0)$ tal que: 
\begin{gather*}
(\forall i \leq 
n-1), (P_i \vtr_{1\beta} P_{i+1}) \mbox {\ ou\ } (P_{i+1} \vtr_{1\beta} 
P_i) \text{ ou } (P_i \equiv_{\alpha} P_{i+1}),\\
P_0 \equiv P, \\
P_n \equiv Q.
\end{gather*}

\begin{exemplo}
Sejam $P\equiv (\lambda xyz.xzy)(\lambda xy.x)$ e $Q\equiv (\lambda 
xy.x)(\lambda x.x)$. Então $P=_{\beta}Q$, ou seja:
\[
(\lambda xyz.xzy)(\lambda xy.x) =_{\beta} (\lambda xy.x)(\lambda x.x)
\]

De fato, pode-se notar inicialmente que:
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
(\lambda xyz.xzy)(\lambda xy.x)
  & \equiv_{\alpha} (\lambda xyz.xzy) (\lambda uv.u) \\
  & \vtr_{1\beta} \lambda yz.(\lambda uv.u)zy \\
  & \vtr_{1\beta} \lambda yz.(\lambda v.z)y \\
  & \vtr_{1\beta} \lambda yz.z
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
Além disso, que:
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
(\lambda xy.x)(\lambda x.x)
  & \equiv_{\alpha} (\lambda xy.x)(\lambda w.w) \\
  & \vtr_{1\beta} \lambda y.(\lambda w.w) \\
  & \equiv \lambda yw.w \\
  & \equiv_{\alpha} \lambda yz.z
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
Finalmente, pode-se considerar $P_0,P_1,P_2,P_3,P_4,P_5,P_6,P_7$ tais 
que:
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
P = P_0 & = (\lambda xyz.xzy)(\lambda xy.x) \\
P_1 & = (\lambda xyz.xzy)(\lambda uv.u) \\
P_2 & = \lambda yz.(\lambda uv.u)zy \\
P_3 & = \lambda yz.(\lambda v.z)y \\
P_4 & = \lambda yz.z \\
P_5 & = \lambda yw.w \\
P_6 & = (\lambda xy.x)(\lambda w.w) \\
Q = P_7 & = (\lambda xy.x)(\lambda x.x)
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
Para concluir que $P=_{\beta}Q$, basta observar que $P_0 
\equiv_{\alpha} P_1$, $P_1 \vtr_{1\beta} P_2$, $P_2 \vtr_{1\beta} P_3$, 
$P_3 \vtr_{1\beta} P_4$, $P_4 \equiv_{\alpha} P_5$, $P_6 \vtr_{1\beta} 
P_5$ e $P_6 \equiv_{\alpha} P_7$.
\end{exemplo}

\end{document}

Of course you have to adjust the values to sensible ones.
Note how the definition of exemplo has been streamlined and made more efficient (and correct).
No LaTeX document should use them, so I fixed them: please, study the fixed code, so you can get a better typesetting.
The following picture is without the settings to \fontdimen, which I really don't think are necessary.


Thank you ver much.
