# Fraction lines?

Tags: fractions

how to bold all fraction lines like in the picture below? I used

```
\newcommand{\thickfrac}[2]{\genfrac{}{}{3pt}{}{#1}{#2}}
```

but nothing happened.

[image]

Comment: If you want to make the horizontal fraction lines thicker, do you want to make other lines thicker as well?

Comment: Yes, all fraction lines :)

Comment: Here's a related question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/79059

Comment: Your code seems correct. I basically use the same in my answer.

Comment: Problem solved?

Comment: The command definition above works well for me. It occurred to me - didn't you forget to change your equation from `\frac{}{}` to `\thickfrac{}{}`? :)

Answer (score 1):

Based on the answer of user [David Carlisle](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/1090/david-carlisle)  from [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/79059) question.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools} % also loads the amsmath package


% Command with 2 obligatory arguments (num and denom)
\newcommand{\myThickFrac}[2]{\genfrac{}{}{5pt}{}{#1}{#2}}

% Command with 2 obligatory arguments (num and denom) and one optional argument (line width)
\newcommand{\myVariableThickFrac}[3][0.4pt]{\genfrac{}{}{#1}{}{#2}{#3}}

\begin{document}

%\genfrac{left-delim}{right-delim}{thickness}{mathstyle}{numerator}{denominator}

\begin{equation}
\genfrac{}{}{5pt}{}{\text{num}}{\text{demom}}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\myThickFrac{\text{num}}{\text{demom}}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\myVariableThickFrac{\text{num}}{\text{demom}} = \myVariableThickFrac[3pt]{\text{num}}{\text{demom}} = \myVariableThickFrac[5pt]{\text{num}}{\text{demom}}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

> Question to the experts here. I don't know why the line width also
>   influences the spacing so much. And I do not know that to do with the remaining arguments `{left-delim}`, `{right-delim}` and `{mathstyle}` (but that is not important here as it seems).

- `\genfrac` is from the very famous `amsmath` package.
- The package `mathtools` that I use here is an extension package to `amsmath`
- `mathtools` loads `amsmath` automatically.
- See [mathtools vs amsmath](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43860) for more details.

From the [`amsmath` manual](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsmath)

[image]

Comment: The other statement (about mathtools) is not quite right. `mathtools` loads `amsmath` and provides additions to it. Nothing in this example needs `mathtools`, `amsmath` is enough

Comment: I was simplifying on purpose. And I wanted to encourage to use mathtools :). I'll update the answer -- feel free to correct me again.

Comment: @daleif I updated the answer and added another question :(. Maybe you can jump in.

Comment: Me again, I just figure it that all lines are bold lines of box, all fraction lines, equal signs are also little bit bold, not bold with /textbf but bolder than mine. Does anyone has solution for that? :)

Comment: @Ana Leko. I don't understand what you mean. Please keep the focus at one question at the time. Is your question from above is answered, which I think it is, then accept the answer. Open a new question with a clear description and a complete but minimal code example (not just some lines of code, fragments) if you have another question.

Comment: the width of the fraction lines is a parameter in the font dimensions (in `.tfm` files).  it is a misfeature in tex that the space above and below the fraction line uses the same dimension parameter.  this is a side effect of the very limited memory available when tex was created, and it's too late to change now.if `.tfm` files are being used for fonts.  i don't know whether the limitation has been addressed in xetex or luatex.

Comment: @barbara Thanks for the detailed explanation.

Comment: So what would be the remedy for this problem?  If I want the 2 lines to be normally spaced?