# Thickness of the fraction line

Tags: fractions

I want to make this fraction line thicker:
[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tgheros}
\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault}
\usepackage{mathastext}
%
\makeatletter
\mathchardef\standardplus=\mathcode`+
\DeclareRobustCommand{\tauyecoplus}{%
  \mathbin{\mathpalette\tauyeco@plus\relax}%
}
\newcommand{\tauyeco@plus}[2]{
  \raisebox{-0.1\height}{\scalebox{1.4}{$\m@th#1\standardplus$}}%
}
\begingroup\lccode`~=`+ \lowercase{\endgroup\let~}\tauyecoplus
\AtBeginDocument{\mathcode`+="8000 }
\makeatother
%
\DeclareRobustCommand{\bfrac}[2]{%
  \mathchoice{\frac{\raisebox{0.1ex}{$#1$}}{\raisebox{-0.1ex}{$#2$}}}%
         {\frac{\raisebox{0.4ex}{$\scriptstyle#1$}}{\raisebox{0.1ex}{$\scriptstyle#2$}}}%
             {\frac{#1}{#2}}%
             {\frac{#1}{#2}}%
}
%
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\[\frac{(x+y)^2}{B_x}\]
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Not width. I want to change the thickness. I'm looking for a code that makes all the fraction lines a little bit thicker.

Comment: see amsmath genfrac  command

Comment: what is the intention of `\bfrac` it seems a bit... strange? scaling + by 1.4 makes it unusably bold compared to the rest of the letters, making fractions bolder is just spreading the bad effects of the initial change.

Comment: Thank you I understood

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/79061/38080

Comment: Yes i did it thanks @Rmano